# Serialize form data into a specific JSON format

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <select name="ItemName" ng-controller="ItemController">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Name}}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="Description" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My AngularJS FormController then does the following:

**form.controller.js**

```
app.controller('FormController', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.submitForm = function () {
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Path/To/MVC/Action',
            data: { json: JSON.stringify($('#myForm').serializeArray()) }
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log('success');
        })
        .error(function(error) {
            console.log('failure);
        });
    };
});
```

I want my MVC controller to receive a json string that looks like this:

```
{
    "Name": "some item name",
    "Description": "some item description"
}
```

With serialize(), I got something like:

```
Name=some%20item%20name&Description=some%20item%20description
```

...and with serializeArray(), I got something like:

```
[{
    name: "Name",
    value: "some item name"
},
{
    name: "Description",
    value: "some item description"
}]
```

How do I get the JSON string in the format I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? I am a little unclear with what items is, etc:

https://plnkr.co/edit/IFHNtxS226Hq0cCMJYi1?p=preview

```
  $scope.submitForm = function(formData){

    console.warn(formData);

    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Path/To/MVC/Action',
            data: { json: formData }
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log('success');
        })
      .error(function(error) {
            console.log('failure');
        })

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WebAPI?

You can replace your select for this:

```
<select id="selectId" type="text" ng-required="true" name="nameOfSelect" class="form-control" ng-model="yourModel.ObjectForThisSelect" placeholder="String Inside you Select"
      ng-options="info.Value as info.Text for info in items>
</select>
```

then you should post back "yourModel" object, this way Angular when posting back will serialize only the selected option value.

Additionally in case you are using WebApi you can check in your WebApiConfig class, Register(HttpConfiguration config) method, that you are formatting Json strings in the desired format: i.e.

```
 var jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
```